Is the Faith of Jesus Christ, the Faith Given Through the Holy Spirit?
This is a follow up question to Austin's post, What is the Faith the Ephesians were saved through (Eph 2:8)
My question is, is the faith OF Jesus Christ faith that comes by the Holy Spirit. Therefore, since the Holy Spirit is a gift, faith is also gift (not of works lest anyone should boast)

Ephesians 1:13-14 And in Him, having heard and believed the word of truth—the gospel of your salvation—you were sealed with the promised Holy Spirit, who is the pledge of our inheritance until the redemption of those who are God’s possession, to the praise of His glory.

We are saved by faith, yet it is the Holy Spirit which seals us with the guarantee of our inheritance (eternal life, Titus 1:2) If we do not have the Spirit of Christ we are none of His (Romans 8:9) The faith of man would be insufficient, we have to be saved by the faith of Christ (i.e. the Holy Spirit)
Would this then explain the concept of faith to faith, the faith of men being that we believed Christ, which lead to baptism, which lead to the receiving of the Holy Spirit, the faith of Jesus Christ. From human faith to Godly faith, from mortal faith to immortal faith. Would this also give clarity to faith without works is dead. The Holy Spirit without the works or the fruits of it (Gal. 5:22-23), is dead.
To make my thoughts more concise, is the Faith of Christ synonymous with the Holy Spirit? And in certain contexts is faith (generalized faith, without a possessive attachment) also synonymous with the Holy Spirit?
I wrote this out the best I can; I hope I've been articulate enough. I know I could spend a couple days in deep Bible Study on this, but seeing your posts and the scriptures you cite will help give me a better guided study when I delve into this this weekend. I appreciate any and all questions regarding this.

Jesus Christ demonstrated his faith in the promises of God, so that, by faith, he always did the will of his Father when he was on Earth. He went to the cross, by faith, trusting in the Father to resurrect him as he had committed no sin. He had faith that the grave could not hold on to him because he believed that "the wages of sin is death" - therefore he had faith that he, the sinless One, would rise in triumph over the grave.
He did not receive such faith as a gift, for he was the Word of God who was with God in the beginning, who was God, and who made everything that was made (John 1:1-3). We sinners, however, cannot muster-up saving faith by our own efforts, even if we mentally assent to everything God declares about it. The Holy Spirit is given to those who are called unto salvation, that they might come from spiritual death to spiritual newness of life, and live forever in the faith of Jesus Christ. It comes by revelation from above.
This is where a mighty lesson is taught through how the Apostle Peter received a revelation as to who Jesus really is. Matthew 16:15-16. Peter openly declared,

"You are the Christ, the Son of the living God, Jesus rejoiced,
saying, "Blessed art thou, Simon Barjona: for flesh and blood hath not
revealed it unto thee, but my Father which is in heaven." A.V.


God chooses who to give such saving faith to. God removes the veil upon our hearts (see 2 Cor. 3:14,15 & 4:6). Christ rejoiced that this was hidden from the wise and prudent, and revealed to babes (Matt. 11:25-27).

That declaration of faith as to just who Jesus really is makes a person a member of Christ's spiritual body, his Church, the ecclesia. They do not decide to 'join' a denomination in fulfilment of Matthew 16:18. Christ joins his own to his own Church, his invisible, spiritual 'body'.

Hearing the gospel of Christ so as to understand it, leading to putting faith in Christ, and grasping the privileges of belonging to Christ's Church all depends on revelation from God in heaven. The Holy Spirit indwells the believer and that is the testimony - the witness - that they are now saved by grace, through faith in Christ alone.


So, the answer is that those who are saved are given faith to believe in Christ as the Son of the living God, whom the Father has revealed to them by revelation, as happened to Simon Peter. "To you it is given to know the mysteries of the kingdom of heaven, but to them it is not given", said Jesus (Matthew 13:11).

"All things are delivered unto me of my Father, and no man knoweth the
Son, but the Father; neither knoweth any man the Father, save the Son
and he to whomsoever the Son will reveal him." Matthew 11:27 A.V.

The Holy Spirit, given from above, reveals all such mysteries. What a gift!

Are you saying that the Philippian jailer was granted the ability to believe...if he did what Paul told him to do for salvation...which was to believe?

@MarkVestal Whom he called, them he also justified. But justification is by faith. Thus whom he calls, he also gives to them the power to  believe. Anyone who has tried to live a Christian life without the power of God will discover it is not possible. Assent and faith are two very different things. I think Anne's answer is quite sel-explanatory, myself.

@NigelJ Up to verse 29 of your citing "Whom He called", Romans 8:29 "For whom he did foreknow, he also did predestinate to be conformed to the image of his Son, that he might be the firstborn among many brethren." Also, 1 Peter 1:2 "Elect according to the foreknowledge of God the Father, through sanctification of the Spirit, unto obedience and sprinkling of the blood of Jesus Christ: Grace unto you, and peace, be multiplied." I agree with you if viewed in light of the calling being based on His "foreknowledge", of those who WILL believe. Anne, you, me, are then all correct.

@MarkVestal Yes, I agree. That is what scripture tells us. Yes, indeed.

Restating the question:

My question is, is the faith OF Jesus Christ faith that comes by the Holy Spirit. Therefore, since the Holy Spirit is a gift, faith is also gift (not of works lest anyone should boast)

and later...

To make my thoughts more concise, is the Faith of Christ synonymous with the Holy Spirit? And in certain contexts is faith (generalized faith, without a possessive attachment) also synonymous with the Holy Spirit?

My understanding of the question is that there is confusion concerning what faith is and who's faith a follower of Jesus possesses.
Paul explains how to be a follower of Jesus in Romans 10:9-13 (NIV)

9 If you declare with your mouth, “Jesus is Lord,” and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be saved. 10 For it is with your heart that you believe and are justified, and it is with your mouth that you profess your faith and are saved. 11 As Scripture says, “Anyone who believes in him will never be put to shame.” 12 For there is no difference between Jew and Gentile—the same Lord is Lord of all and richly blesses all who call on him, 13 for, “Everyone who calls on the name of the Lord will be saved.”
14 How, then, can they call on the one they have not believed in? And how can they believe in the one of whom they have not heard? And how can they hear without someone preaching to them? 15 And how can anyone preach unless they are sent? As it is written: “How beautiful are the feet of those who bring good news!”
16 But not all the Israelites accepted the good news. For Isaiah says, “Lord, who has believed our message?” 17 Consequently, faith comes from hearing the message, and the message is heard through the word about Christ.

Notice that believing and faith are connected
Paul says,

"Believe with your heart and are justified" v10
"Profess your faith and are saved" v11
If we hear and believe then we can call on the name of the Lord v14
v16 "not all the Israelites accepted the good news" they didn't believe and therefore had no faith.

To be a follower of Jesus one must accept the good news, believe the good news. The good news becomes the truth that we trust in, that one must profess our faith in.
The author of Hebrews directly addresses what faith is:
Hebrews 11:1-3 (NIV)

1 Now faith is confidence in what we hope for and assurance about what we do not see. 2 This is what the ancients were commended for.
3 By faith we understand that the universe was formed at God’s command, so that what is seen was not made out of what was visible.

Looking at the Ephesians 2 passage (NIV)

4 But because of his great love for us, God, who is rich in mercy, 5 made us alive with Christ even when we were dead in transgressions—it is by grace you have been saved. 6 And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with him in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus, 7 in order that in the coming ages he might show the incomparable riches of his grace, expressed in his kindness to us in Christ Jesus. 8 For it is by grace you have been saved, through faith—and this is not from yourselves, it is the gift of God— 9 not by works, so that no one can boast.

v8
"it is by grace you have been saved" salvation is the gift by grace
"through faith" - faith is how we receive the gift, the gift "is not from yourselves, it is the gift of God"
To be a follower of Jesus one must believe, accept the good news in order so that the gift provided by the grace of God can be received.
It is we who must believe and accept. That belief is faith "faith is confidence in what we hope for and assurance about what we do not see" Heb 11:1.
The gift is redemption, salvation, reconciliation with God through the death and resurrection of Jesus given by the grace of God.
A follower of Jesus has faith in the good news and receives the gift of the Holy Spirit.
A follower of Jesus does not have the faith of Jesus

It is a great answer, David.  I agree that "a follower of Jesus does not have the faith of Jesus"...literally, but they do positionally with God.  Their standing before Him has changed from not having it, to having it, as to Him they are now "in Christ". +1

@MarkVestal Positionally - spiritually speaking -  followers of Jesus are righteous before God. 2 Corinthians 5:21 "God made him who had no sin to be sin for us, so that in him we might become the righteousness of God."

Yes, I believe we are on the same page.

“God hath dealt to every_man the measure of faith”. Romans 12:3.  But it is not clear to me whether ἕκαστος means literally every human or just each of the Romans Paul was writing to.

@WGroleau The passage 12:1-8 is about how followers of Jesus should be humble and use the "different gifts, according to the grace given to each of us" v6 as part of "one body".

The faith that God requires was completed by Jesus Christ on our behalf.  His faithfulness is imputed to those who believe in Christ.  When someone believes in Christ, more specifically, believes that the faith that Christ maintained was for the benefit of the believer (we do not have the ability to merit it on our own accord), the believer is then gifted the very righteousness of God (Rom 3:22)...which includes the faith requirement of God.
The believer is now seen by God (positionally) as having the very faith requirement that Christ alone maintained for the world, as they have now been placed "in Christ" by the Spirit.  This is not to imply that a believer will now live a perfect and righteous life for God, but it is the means by which (because of their awareness of what God did for them out of His love) a believer will begin to now live after the Spirit, rather than a continued life of serving their carnal desires of the flesh, which is sin (Romans chapter 7).
Every person on earth has the ability to believe (1 Tim 2:3-4).  The Philippian jailer asked Paul "what must I do to be saved?"  Paul's answer was to "believe on the Lord Jesus Christ" (Acts 16:30-31).  Notice that Paul's answer was not to "hope that you're one of God's chosen".  This alone tells us that belief is on the part of the believer.  It is belief in Christ's faithfulness (1 Cor 15:1-4) that the gift of Christ's faithfulness is then imputed to the believer.  Yes, belief is then doing something ourselves, but it is not a "work", and it is not THE faith that is imputed.
Romans 3:20-26

Therefore by the deeds of the law there shall no flesh be justified in his sight: for by the law is the knowledge of sin.
21 But now the righteousness of God without the law is manifested, being witnessed by the law and the prophets;
22 Even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ unto all and upon all them that believe: for there is no difference:
23 For all have sinned, and come short of the glory of God;
24 Being justified freely by his grace through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus:
25 Whom God hath set forth to be a propitiation through faith in his blood, to declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that are past, through the forbearance of God;
26 To declare, I say, at this time his righteousness: that he might be just, and the justifier of him which believeth in Jesus.

Why would the world need ministers of reconciliation (2 Cor 5:18) if God simply allows a believer to believe?  It is by hearing and believing what the word of reconciliation states that the believer is then gifted the faith of Christ.  The Holy Spirit seals the believer at the moment of belief (Eph 1:12-13) and until the day of redemption (Eph 4:30).  Yes, this baptism that is performed by Him and into the church, the body of Christ, (1 Cor 12:13) would certainly also be one of our gifted spiritual blessings (Eph 1:3).
Romans 10:13-17

For whosoever shall call upon the name of the Lord shall be saved.
14 How then shall they call on him in whom they have not believed? and how shall they believe in him of whom they have not heard? and how shall they hear without a preacher?
15 And how shall they preach, except they be sent? as it is written, How beautiful are the feet of them that preach the gospel of peace, and bring glad tidings of good things!
16 But they have not all obeyed the gospel. For Esaias saith, Lord, who hath believed our report?
17 So then faith cometh by hearing, and hearing by the word of God.

What is the word of reconciliation?
1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

2 Corinthians 5:17-21

Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new.
18 And all things are of God, who hath reconciled us to himself by Jesus Christ, and hath given to us the ministry of reconciliation;
19 To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation.
20 Now then we are ambassadors for Christ, as though God did beseech you by us: we pray you in Christ's stead, be ye reconciled to God.
21 For he hath made him to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him.

To summarize:
It is by having faith (belief) in Christ, that one is gifted the faith of Christ, sealed by the Spirit Himself and into Christ's body, and gifted all spiritual blessings in heavenly places until Christ returns for His purchased possession, which is the believer in Christ.
